# Random data generator

Tags: testing, generator

I have a set of tables in a relational schema.
e.g. Customers, Departments, Branches etc and so on...
All of them are related via some referential integrity constraints FK's and all..

I need to fill up these tables with huge data for testing purpose.
generating CSV's is also fine, I can then load the data in the table.

Any open source tool that can help me with this?
I know there are some tools available, but they seem to be only for generating random data for a single table not for related tables.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rosh, you may want to check out [Benerator](http://databene.org/databene-benerator).  If you're using Java and Maven, you can even wire it up as part of your build using the maven plugin.  You can configure it to do some fairly complex data generation across multiple tables.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Just checked it out. As per the documentation and reviews it looks quite impressive. However the setup is quite complex. Any tutorial that you can point to for this which explains with an example? Thanks again for pointing out to this wonderful tool.

Comment: Yeah, the web seems to be a little thin on tutorials for Benerator.  I think your best bet is to download it (http://bergmann-it.de/download/download_benerator?lang=en) and take a look.  I haven't downloaded it in a while, but I seem to recall that there are some examples and tutorials as part of the download package.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I just used the tool to generate 2 inter-related CSV files. Smthng as per my requirement. However i found the tool too slow and it thew memory errors when i started gnerating extremely huge amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to have to write code, try [Mockaroo](http://www.mockaroo.com).  It's very flexible and you can save multiple schemas.  It also allows you to automate data generation from your saved schemas using curl.

Answer (score -1):

You can use "Lorem Ipsum Generator" tool or you can use "generatedata.com"(http://www.generatedata.com/) tool.
I hope it will helpful to you.

Thanks
Khushboo

Comment: Thnks Khushboo. This is also good but it works for a single file.